# Dynamically changing screen size in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm making a game in AS3, using FlashDevelop. I'm trying to, as the title says, dynamically increase the size of the screen. It's a simple avoider-type game, so one of the upgrades I'm letting the player unlock is more space.

I have my main, and that main has a single child. I'm trying to call an `UpgradeScreen()` function from that child. I've tried several permutations of `stage.stageWidth` and `stage.scaleX` and nothing has worked so far. Based on some of the responses to questions of this nature that I've found it looks like it's going to be more complicated than I was hoping.

So, is what I'm trying possible? Should I have the child call a function in the main instead of trying to do it itself?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this browser-based or an AIR app?

Comment: It depends on two things: What platform are you trying to deploy to, and what do you mean by changing the screen size?

Comment: Assuming you mean change the game board size, sure you can change that. The size of the application window is static unless using AIR

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say browser-based. I don't know for sure though, since this is my first as3-based project.

Comment: You create your game with the biggest size you want, then you use logical clipping to limit the dsisplayed portion of the game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the advice of Vesper, I made the project size larger, and used clipping. I'm not a fan of the fact that there's a white border until the screen is at its maximum upgrade, but there probably isn't an easy way to avoid that...

Instead of binding everything by `(0,0)` and `(stage.stageWidth,stage.stageHeight)`. I am now binding things by `(LeftX,TopY)` and `(myWidth,myHeight)` and when I run `UpgradeScreen()` I subtract 5 from both `LeftX` and `TopY` and add 10 to both `myWidth` and `myHeight`